# Connect two mac computers/servers using a tunnel or private VPN?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, tunnel

I've got software I need to run on two computers on two separate networks (one behind a nat). The software requires both sides to have a static ip address that doesnt change.

I assume some sort of tunnel or vpn would be a neat way to solve this, assigning each computer a private ip address.

What is the best way to do this?

(A hosted server and my home server need to stay connected and recover should somehting happen with my isp like a changed IP address.)

Comment: Best depends on 3 things, budget, need for security, and your ability.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the exact use but for only two pcs or a single server an pc you may try teamviewer. Its very easy to use. You may know that software used for remote support but you can create VPN tunnels with that software as well. IP changes wouldnt be a big problem because you have a static ID you can use to connect to that network.

www.teamviewer.com